# Android loadUrl unable to load site

Tags: android, webview

My webview will works for a site such as Google.com, however, the specific page will not load.

Simply displays `subscribe to feedburner` (I made this site to reflect a converted news feed)

This specific webpage will display correctly in an Iphone UIWebView, but not for Android.

Some code

```
WebView rss = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewRSS);
rss.loadUrl("www.newmanu.edu/newmannews");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the source of "www.newmanu.edu/newmannews", you have to activate javascript.

from http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `http://` or `https://` before URL.

Try this.

```
rss.loadUrl("http://www.newmanu.edu/newmannews");
```

Or

```
rss.loadUrl("https://www.newmanu.edu/newmannews");
```